# How to get X-Scale and Y-Scale in UIView?

Tags: objective-c, ios

If I have many subviews in myView (all views is instance of UIView) and I set transform of each subview, may be I its setScale, rotation or etc. How to know the xscale and yscale of each subview that I have set it?

for example:

```
  subview1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(xscale1, yscale1);
  subview1.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(subview1.transform, angle1);
  subview2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(xscale2, yscale2);
  subview2.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(subview2.transform, angle2);
   .
   .
  subviewx.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(xscalex, yscalex);
  subviewx.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(subviewx.transform, angle3);
```

From example user set something in subview.transform, I need to know xscale and yscale after user set it. I think it's some equation to solve, please help me. ^_^

Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation [CGAffineTransform](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) make note of the function `CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformMakeScale (
   CGFloat sx,
   CGFloat sy
);`. You can get the scale of the view like this

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 0.5), CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4));
CGFloat xScale = view.transform.a / cosf(M_PI_4);
CGFloat yScale = view.transform.d  / cosf(M_PI_4);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but if user set rotation after set scale the result is not corrected.

Comment: Have you tried performing the rotation first and then scaling? The order of performing matrix operations is important. Also check this function CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformConcat (
   CGAffineTransform t1,
   CGAffineTransform t2
);

Answer (score 1):

you can get x and y scale for your subviews following code:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.yourView.subviews)
{

        CGRect framelb1=subview.frame;
        NSNumber *num;
        NSNumber *ynum;
        num =[NSNumber numberWithInt:framelb1.origin.x];//x-value of subview
        ynum =[NSNumber numberWithInt:framelb1.origin.y];//y-value of subview
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your code does not yield the scale of the subviews but their origins plus why would you create instances of NSNumber in a for loop for this particular operation?

Answer (score 0):

you can get all subviews of view by -

```
NSArray *subViews = myView.subviews;
```

Now at the time of creation of your child views you can set tag property to them, and here on the basis o tag you can fetch individual view and perform task that you want.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to apply the transform on `CGRect` and then compare with the original `CGRect` :

```
CGRect transformedBounds = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(self.bounds, self.transform);
CGFloat currScale = transformedBounds.size.width/ self.bounds.size.width;
```